# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut brings the img on top

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script to slide through a series of images which are fit to the page. But at the top I have a jquery navigation. When my mouse is over a menu with submenu, it naturally slides down the submenu, and submenu hovers the images (which are sliding).

BUT, when the image is going to fade out, it comes on top of the part of navigation hovering it. I don't know how to solve it.

True version works in this site: http://www.zillow.com/

Mine is okay but when image is fading in/out, it comes on the part of navigation menu.

Files are too relative, it is quite hard to copy-paste them here. Thanks in advance.

But here is the snapshot of the moment that image is fading.

http://8pic.ir/images/12749369238552817836.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS,

Try using `z-index: 99999;` for your submenu element. And `z-index:0;` for your image container.

Answer (score 2):

Apply highest Z-index for the whole navigation container. Applying it to only sub-menu may not work. So apply it to main parent. Can't help you more, as we don't have any insight into your code.